# How to impose fixed length fields

Tags: mysql, sql, char

For exercise, I need to write the code for a table which respects this constraint:
field ID must be EXACTLY of 10 characters, starting alway for 'ID_' and terminating with '000'.
I thought something like this:

```
create table xyz (id char(10) primary key, check (id like 'ID\_%000'))
```

But as I've seen id can be less than 10 character.
Is there a way to impose an exact lenght for a field? Or, maybe, I need to use something like triggers? And in that case, how?
Thanks.

Comment: 10 characters different by space? When you create a field with char type (and not varchar) if you put 3 characthers, MySql padded with initial spaces to reach the defined dimension

Comment: does mysql support check constraints ?

Comment: Yes, I know that.
I think the exercise asks something like this: if I try to insert an ID like ID_abc000 (which is less than 10 chars) or ID_abcdefctfga000 (which is more than 10 chars), it can't be permitted.

Comment: Mysql doesn't support check constraints. But SQL do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 4 underscores as wildcards in 'like' (that's why you had to backslash the first underscore)

```
create table xyz (id char(10) primary key, check (id like 'ID\_____000'))
```

Comment: Yes, it can be a solution. But what if I have to do the same thing through a trigger or a procedure or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: google 'mysql trigger before insert validate input': http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/